# program flow animating in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, animation, dynamic

Hello I am having errors with my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/wzhm2whj/

```js
<script>
    //Initial Global variables
    var mainloop_frame_time = 34;
    var top = 0;
    var rootMenu = document.getElementById('menu');
    var rootMenuDivs = rootMenu.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
    var rootListDivs = rootMenuDivs.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
    var childDivs = rootListDivs.getElementsByTagName('div');
    var childDiv = childDivs[0];
    var childDiv_counter = 0;
    var child_change_flag = true;
    var child_index_increment = 0;
    var child_index_amount = childDivs.length;
    //var child_animation_keyframe = 0;
    var frame = 0;
    var childDiv_tmp1_position = 0;

    //finding the web browsers viewport size.
    var elem = (document.compatMode === "CSS1Compat") ? document.documentElement : document.body;
    var client_height = elem.clientHeight;

    var process_array = new Array();
    //Initial styling
    for (var i = 0; i < childDivs.length; i++) {
        var childDiv = childDivs[0];
        childDiv.style.backgroundColor = "antiquewhite";
    }
    var childDiv = childDivs[0];

    //rotate function variables
    var rotate_div;
    var rotate_passed_deg;
    var rotate_deg_stop;
    var rotate_results;
    var rotate_current_deg = 0;

    var speed_modifier = 1;
    var tmp1_speed = 0;

    //case flags
    case2_flag = -1;
    case3_flag = -1;



    //This may not be needed >>> If not, put all code in mainloop.
    var processes_logic = function() {
        switch (frame) {
            case 0:
                process_array.push(menu_child0);
                break;
                //this case is when the previous case is 80% done
            case 28:
                rootMenu.style.transformOrigin = "top left";
                process_array.push(menu_slant);
                break;
            case 35:
                //Added the ability for paramaters, all push paramaters here are: function,      menu_index,      position, speed,      tmp as flag for switching to next menu, 
                //process_index used to give the process index as refrence to delete..
                window.alert(process_array.length);
                process_array.push(new Array(menu_div_slide_out, child_index_amount - 1, 0, 0, 0, process_array.length-1));

                break;
        }
    }


    var initiate_all_processes = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < process_array.length; i++) {
            //Added the ability for paramaters, considerer removing as its not used atm, or revising.
            if (process_array[i] != undefined && process_array[i] != null && process_array[i] != "") {
                if (process_array[i].length < 6) {
                    process_array[i]();
                } else {
                    process_array[i][0](process_array[i][5]);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    function menu_div_slide_out(process_index) {
        /*process_array[process_index][
        0 = function,
        1 = current menu item (index length working backwards)
        2 = position,
        3 = speed,
        4 = tmp,
        5 = refrence to this process in array] */
        //for debuging purposes to see if a ChildDiv is not devined, what process index is being pointed to.
      
            //window.alert('Process index ' + process_index);
        //!!!!!!!! You are probably mixing up how you are setting process index! try +1
        process_array[process_index][2] += 3.5 + (process_array[process_index][3] * 1.7);
        process_array[process_index][3] += (speed_modifier * .3);
        childDivs[process_array[process_index][1]].style.left = process_array[process_index][2] + 'px';


        if (process_array[process_index][2] > 100 && process_array[process_index][4] && process_array[process_index][1] > 0) {
           // window.alert('CCC');
            process_array[process_index][4] = true;
           //Add another process at ever 100pxs
            process_array.push(new Array(menu_div_slide_out, process_array[process_index][1] - 1, 0, 0, false, process_array.length-1));
            //debugger;

        } else
        if (process_array[process_index][2] >= (900 - (process_array[process_index][2] / 20))) {
            childDivs[process_array[process_index][1]].remove();
            //process_array.splice(process_array[process_index][5], 1);
        }
    }


    function menu_slant() {
        rotate_return = rotate(rootMenu, .1 + (tmp1_speed), 27);
        tmp1_speed += (speed_modifier * .5);
        if (rotate_return === true) {
            /////////////This can be unremoved because there is more animation, perhaps. or can be done in another key frame.
            tmp1_speed = 0;
            rotate_current_deg = 0;
            remove_process(menu_slant);
        } else {
            if (rotate_return / 27 * 100 >= 60 && case3_flag < 0) {
                case2_flag = frame;
            }
        }
    }




    var menu_child0 = function() {
        childDiv_tmp1_position += 3 + (tmp1_speed * 1.7);
        childDiv.style.top = childDiv_tmp1_position + 'px';
        rotate(childDiv, .2 + (tmp1_speed), 170);
        tmp1_speed += (speed_modifier * .7);
        if (childDiv_tmp1_position / client_height * 100 >= 80 && case2_flag < 0) {
            case2_flag = frame;
        }
        if (childDiv_tmp1_position >= client_height) {
            childDiv.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            tmp1_speed = 0;
            childDiv_tmp1_position = 0;
            rotate_current_deg = 0;
            //may be bloated >>
            remove_process(menu_child0);
        }
    }


    function remove_process(index) {
        var index_tmp = process_array.indexOf(index);
        if (index_tmp >= 0) {
            process_array.splice(index_tmp, 1);
        }
    }


    function rotate(rotate_div, rotate_passed_deg, rotate_passed_deg_stop) {
        rotate_current_deg += rotate_passed_deg;
        rotate_deg = rotate_current_deg < rotate_passed_deg_stop ? rotate_current_deg : rotate_passed_deg_stop;
        rotate_div.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(' + rotate_deg + 'deg)';
        rotate_div.style.mozTransform = 'rotate(' + rotate_deg + 'deg)';
        rotate_div.style.msTransform = 'rotate(' + rotate_deg + 'deg)';
        rotate_div.style.oTransform = 'rotate(' + rotate_deg + 'deg)';
        rotate_div.style.transform = 'rotate(' + rotate_deg + 'deg)';
        if (rotate_current_deg >= rotate_passed_deg_stop) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return rotate_current_deg;
        }
    }




    //main loop for the animation
    var mainloop = function() {
        processes_logic();
        initiate_all_processes();
        frame++;
    }
    var loop_interval = setInterval(mainloop, mainloop_frame_time);
</script>
```

I am trying to animate my website falling apart but I am having a hard time articulation this into code. I thought of running the animation in a loop, creating events at specific frames and reusing some codes as functions. I have a rotate function which works to rotate several things.

**THE PROBLEM**:
The problem I am having is sliding my menu items one at a time to the right. I want one to slide a bit and the next to start sliding after. I wrote a function to slide an item and then in that function it adds another process to an array for the next menu item to be called and run the same function (with passed interval of who is calling). I do not know how many menu items there will be, thats why I am trying to make it dynamic.

I can get it so that the first mwnu item falls, the menu falls by rotating it (some times if there is an error in the code then it wont rotate, but when there are no errors it works better).

The issue is sliding each menu item.

my website is here: http://clearlove.ca/89-404-error

Can any one help me with why this isnt working, and if there is a better way to do what I am trying to do?